# Intercept all classes in application with Unity

Tags: .net-4.5, unity-container, interceptor

I want to use interceptor in my application in order to do logging.
Of course I could register each type with interceptor like this:

```
container.AddNewExtension<Interception>();
container.RegisterType<ITenantStore, TenantStore>(
new Interceptor<InterfaceInterceptor>(),
new InterceptionBehavior<LoggingInterceptionBehavior>());
```

but since I have a lot of types I was wondering if there's a cleaner way to do this for all my classes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a method that will enable interception on all types that have already been registered.  So call this after your registrations are complete.  Then you can use [Policy Injection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn178466(v=pandp.30).aspx#sec15) to hook up the interceptors you want to use.

```
public static class UnityContainerInterceptionExtensions
{
    public static IUnityContainer EnableInterceptionForAllRegisteredTypes
        (this IUnityContainer unityContainer)
    {
        unityContainer
            .Registrations
            .ForEach(r => unityContainer.EnableInterception(r.RegisteredType, r.Name));

        return unityContainer;
    }

    public static IUnityContainer EnableInterception<T>
        (this IUnityContainer unityContainer, string name = null)
    {
        return unityContainer.EnableInterception(typeof (T), name);
    }

    public static IUnityContainer EnableInterception
        (this IUnityContainer unityContainer, Type registrationType, string name = null)
    {
        // Don't allow interception of unity types
        if (registrationType.Namespace.StartsWith(typeof(IUnityContainer).Namespace))
            return unityContainer;

        // Don't allow interception on the intercepting call handlers
        if (typeof (ICallHandler).IsAssignableFrom(registrationType))
            return unityContainer;

        var interception = unityContainer.Configure<Interception>();

        var interfaceInterceptor = new InterfaceInterceptor();
        if (interfaceInterceptor.CanIntercept(registrationType))
        {
            interception
                .SetInterceptorFor(registrationType, name, interfaceInterceptor);
            return unityContainer;
        }

        var virtualMethodInterceptor = new VirtualMethodInterceptor();
        if (virtualMethodInterceptor.CanIntercept(registrationType))
        {
            interception
                .SetInterceptorFor(registrationType, name, virtualMethodInterceptor);
            return unityContainer;
        }

        var transparentProxyInterceptor = new TransparentProxyInterceptor();
        if (transparentProxyInterceptor.CanIntercept(registrationType))
        {
            interception
                .SetInterceptorFor(registrationType, name, transparentProxyInterceptor);
            return unityContainer;
        }

        return unityContainer;
    }
}
```

Comment: And the InterceptionBehavior? Where are they?